Initialising @State Variables in a View
I have a view which uses an observable class for some of its data. I looks something like this:
@Observable
class Data {
    var note: String
    var original: String
    init(id: String) {
        self.note = "Note for \(id): "
        self.original = "Note for \(id): "      // why not self.original = self.note ?
    }
}

struct Test: View {
    //  Redundant initialisation:
        @State var id: String = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
        @State var data: Data = Data(id: "")
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(id)
            Text(data.note)
        }
        .onAppear {
            id = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
            data = Data(id: id)
            print(data.note)
        }
    }
}

There are two things which confuse me:

Why can’t I use the expression self.original = self.note above? I get the error message: 'self' used in property access 'note' before all stored properties are initialized
I have to initialise the two @State variables to something, so that they don’t become input parameters, but I really want to initialise them in the .onAppear section to keep them up to date.

Is there a correct way to declare the @State variables without initialising them? Also,  is there a way to use self.original = self.note above?

Note, Swift already has a Data structure, rename your class
to something else, you will confuse yourself and the compiler.
You cannot refer self.note in init because vars will only get fully initialised
as the init finishes.
Use this instead: init(id: String) {   let temp = "Note for \(id): "   self.note = temp   self.original = temp  }.
Note, do not make @Observable class conform to ObservableObject and do not use @StateObject for @Observable class, see
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app.  Use @State private ...

Just make the State properties optional. Have a loading screen then the screen when the optionals are loaded.

@State is just for structs because its initial value is init every time the View is init, which isn't a problem for simple stack values but for heap objects it would be a memory leak.
You can workaround the problem with an optional @State and init the object in onAppear, deinit it in onDisappear but often the behaviour isn’t right and you probably wont achieve what @StateObject already offers so right now it's best to use that and it works fine with @Observable.
Since your data doesn't actually need a class you might be better of just changing it to a struct and then you can use @State, e.g.
struct Data { 
    var id = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!

    var note: String {
        "Note for \(id): "
    }

    var original: String {
        "Note for \(id): "
    }
}

struct Test: View {
    @State var data: data = Data()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(data.id)
            Text(data.note)
        }
        // you could use .onReceive here to get the new frontmost app if it changes
    }
}

